# Websphere V8.5 get BeanManager over JNDI

Tags: jndi, websphere-8, bean-manager

I have a custom ConstraintValidatorFactory which shall get a BeanManager over JNDI.
I use a custom factory to inject ressources in my validator classes.

The application getting deployed on a Websphere V8.5.

But when i use my validator the injected values return always null.

This works like a charm with JBoss.

My thought is that WebSphere has another JNDI ID for the Ressource.

```
import javax.enterprise.context.spi.CreationalContext;
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.Bean;
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NameClassPair;
import javax.naming.NamingEnumeration;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorFactory;

public class CDIConstraintValidatorFactory implements
    ConstraintValidatorFactory {

    private static BeanManager beanManager;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public <T extends ConstraintValidator<?, ?>> T getInstance(Class<T> clazz) {
        // lazily initialize the beanManager
        if (beanManager == null) {
            try {
                InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
                beanManager = (BeanManager) InitialContext
                        .doLookup("java:comp/env/BeanManager");
            } catch (NamingException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }

        T result = null;

        Bean<T> bean = (Bean<T>) beanManager.resolve(beanManager
                .getBeans(clazz));
        if (bean != null) {
            CreationalContext<T> context = beanManager
                    .createCreationalContext(bean);
            if (context != null) {
                result = (T) beanManager.getReference(bean, clazz, context);
            }
        } else {
            try {
                result = clazz.newInstance();
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                throw new RuntimeException(t);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public void releaseInstance(ConstraintValidator<?, ?> instance) {
    }

}
```

*** UPDATE ***

I tried to inject the BeanManager in my controller with @Resource and get following stacktrace:

```
[15.08.14 14:26:28:711 CEST] 00000087 AnnotatedElem E AnnotatedElementFactory error AnnotatedType für Klasse : [mypackage.MyClass] kann nicht erstellt werden. Ausnahmeursache: [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager]
                             java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFieldsImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:607)
at org.apache.webbeans.util.SecurityUtil$PrivilegedActionForClass.run(SecurityUtil.java:141)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:229)
at org.apache.webbeans.util.SecurityUtil.doPrivilegedGetDeclaredFields(SecurityUtil.java:102)
at org.apache.webbeans.portable.AnnotatedElementFactory.newAnnotatedType(AnnotatedElementFactory.java:100)
at org.apache.webbeans.config.BeansDeployer.deployFromClassPath(BeansDeployer.java:484)
at org.apache.webbeans.config.BeansDeployer.deploy(BeansDeployer.java:171)
at org.apache.webbeans.lifecycle.AbstractLifeCycle.startApplication(AbstractLifeCycle.java:124)
at org.apache.webbeans.web.lifecycle.WebContainerLifecycle.startApplication(WebContainerLifecycle.java:78)
at com.ibm.ws.webbeans.common.CommonLifeCycle.startApplication(CommonLifeCycle.java:106)
at com.ibm.ws.webbeans.services.JCDIServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(JCDIServletContainerInitializer.java:85)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initializeServletContainerInitializers(WebAppImpl.java:613)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:409)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:88)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:169)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:749)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:634)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:426)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:718)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1175)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1370)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:639)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startModule(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1684)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.access$700(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:222)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl$3.run(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1619)
at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5474)
at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5600)
at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl._startModule(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1648)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:49)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:256)
at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean$4.run(RequiredModelMBean.java:1148)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:252)
at com.ibm.oti.security.CheckedAccessControlContext.securityCheck(CheckedAccessControlContext.java:30)
at sun.misc.JavaSecurityAccessWrapper.doIntersectionPrivilege(JavaSecurityAccessWrapper.java:41)
at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1142)
at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:995)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:848)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:774)
at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1335)
at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1228)
at com.ibm.ws.management.application.sync.StartDeploymentTask.startDeployment(StartDeploymentTask.java:247)
at com.ibm.ws.management.application.sync.StartDeploymentTask.fineGrainUpdate(StartDeploymentTask.java:198)
at com.ibm.ws.management.application.sync.StartDeploymentTask.performTask(StartDeploymentTask.java:105)
at com.ibm.ws.management.application.sync.AppBinaryProcessor$ExpandApp.expand(AppBinaryProcessor.java:1711)
at com.ibm.ws.management.application.sync.AppBinaryProcessor.postProcessSynchronousExt(AppBinaryProcessor.java:751)
at com.ibm.ws.management.bla.sync.BLABinaryProcessor.postProcess(BLABinaryProcessor.java:599)
at com.ibm.ws.management.bla.sync.BLABinaryProcessor.onChangeCompletion(BLABinaryProcessor.java:476)
at com.ibm.ws.management.bla.sync.BinaryProcessorWrapper.onChangeCompletion(BinaryProcessorWrapper.java:109)
at com.ibm.ws.management.repository.FileRepository.postNotify(FileRepository.java:1924)
at com.ibm.ws.management.repository.FileRepository.update(FileRepository.java:1433)
at com.ibm.ws.management.repository.client.LocalConfigRepositoryClient.update(LocalConfigRepositoryClient.java:189)
at com.ibm.ws.sm.workspace.impl.WorkSpaceMasterRepositoryAdapter.update(WorkSpaceMasterRepositoryAdapter.java:665)
at com.ibm.ws.sm.workspace.impl.RepositoryContextImpl.update(RepositoryContextImpl.java:1998)
at com.ibm.ws.sm.workspace.impl.RepositoryContextImpl.synch(RepositoryContextImpl.java:1946)
at com.ibm.ws.sm.workspace.impl.WorkSpaceImpl.synch(WorkSpaceImpl.java:549)
at com.ibm.ws.management.configservice.ConfigServiceImpl.save(ConfigServiceImpl.java:719)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:49)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:256)
at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean$4.run(RequiredModelMBean.java:1148)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:252)
at com.ibm.oti.security.CheckedAccessControlContext.securityCheck(CheckedAccessControlContext.java:30)
at sun.misc.JavaSecurityAccessWrapper.doIntersectionPrivilege(JavaSecurityAccessWrapper.java:41)
at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1142)
at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:995)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:848)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:774)
at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1335)
at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1228)
at com.ibm.ws.management.remote.AdminServiceForwarder.invoke(AdminServiceForwarder.java:346)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1465)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:85)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1306)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1398)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
at javax.management.remote.rmi._RMIConnectionImpl_Tie.invoke(_RMIConnectionImpl_Tie.java:751)
at javax.management.remote.rmi._RMIConnectionImpl_Tie._invoke(_RMIConnectionImpl_Tie.java:158)
at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ServerDelegate.dispatchInvokeHandler(ServerDelegate.java:669)
at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ServerDelegate.dispatch(ServerDelegate.java:523)
at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.ORB.process(ORB.java:523)
at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ORB.process(ORB.java:1575)
at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.Connection.doRequestWork(Connection.java:3039)
at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.Connection.doWork(Connection.java:2922)
at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.WorkUnitImpl.doWork(WorkUnitImpl.java:64)
at com.ibm.ejs.oa.pool.PooledThread.run(ThreadPool.java:118)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1862)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:434)
at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.findClass(ExtClassLoader.java:204)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:688)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:667)
at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.loadClass(ExtClassLoader.java:119)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:650)
at com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader.loadClass(ProtectionClassLoader.java:62)
at com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader.loadClass(ProtectionClassLoader.java:58)
at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:584)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:650)
at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:584)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:650)
... 105 more
```

*** UPDATE ****

After i tried a lot of things i create the ValidatorFactory by hand as described [here](http://beanvalidation.org/proposals/BVAL-238/)

```
@Inject BeanManager beanManager;

...

    ValidatorFactory validatorFactory = Validation.byDefaultProvider()
            .configure()
            .constraintValidatorFactory(new CDIConstraintValidatorFactory(beanManager))
            .buildValidatorFactory();
    Validator validator = validatorFactory.getValidator();
```

Inside an EJB I can get the BeanManager over regular @Inject and put it in the constructor of my Custom ConstraintValidatorFactory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works both ways using injection and JNDI. Your JNDI name was incorrect. It is `java:comp/BeanManager` as documentation says - [BeanManager javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/enterprise/inject/spi/BeanManager.html)

Injecting via @Resource like this:

```
@Resource
BeanManager bmanager;
```

Using JNDI:

```
   InitialContext ctx;
   try {
        ctx = new InitialContext();
        BeanManager bm2 = (BeanManager) ctx.lookup("java:comp/BeanManager");
        System.out.println("bm2: " + bm2);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Remember that you need to have `beans.xml` file in the WEB-INF folder to enable CDI.

UPDATE
If it initializes correctly you should see following messages in the log:

```
[8/15/14 12:41:40:493 CEST] 00000088 WebContainerL I WebContainerLifecycle startApplication OpenWebBeans Container is starting...
[8/15/14 12:41:40:556 CEST] 00000088 BeansDeployer I BeansDeployer validateInjectionPoints All injection points were validated successfully.
[8/15/14 12:41:40:571 CEST] 00000088 WebContainerL I WebContainerLifecycle startApplication OpenWebBeans Container has started, it took [78] ms.
```

UPDATE 2
Here is my simple servlet which works. You probably have some conflicting jars in your WEB-INF/lib folder. Either try to remove conflicting ones, or try with PARENT_LAST class loader.

```
@WebServlet("/BeanManagerServlet")
public class BeanManagerServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Resource
    private BeanManager bmanager;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("Bmanager from annotation: " + bmanager);
        out.println("<BR><BR>");

        try {
            InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
            BeanManager bm2 = (BeanManager) ctx.lookup("java:comp/BeanManager");
            out.println("Bmanager from JNDI: " + bm2);
            out.println("<BR><BR>");
            out.println(bm2.getClass().getName());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

// gives output:
Bmanager from annotation: com.ibm.ws.webbeans.services.IBMBeanManagerImpl@ffd28a40 
Bmanager from JNDI: com.ibm.ws.webbeans.services.IBMBeanManagerImpl@ffd28a40 
com.ibm.ws.webbeans.services.IBMBeanManagerImpl
```

Comment: Hmm i will test to inject the BeanManager over @Resource. But i also used "java:comp/BeanManager" without success. Just realized that the beans.xml is in the wrong path {module}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/beans.xml. I will change this and give you a feedback.

Comment: @Resource doesn't work because this Class is not managed by the controller. I placed the beans.xml this time on the right place but it change nothing.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I've tested @Resource from web service, so it worked. But JNDI lookup works form anywhere. Did you fix JNDI name?  Ensure that webbeans container initializes correctly (see answer update).

Comment: I fixed the JNDI name and found also the log output as mentioned in your update. Hmm something must go wrong here.

Comment: How and where your factory is created? Try to create test servlet and see if you will be able to lookup beanmanager then.

Comment: I run it in an a Webservlet and in an EJB. Both work like a charm. The factory class is obviously not managed by the container so it can't find the ressource.

Comment: I accept your answer because i get from you the conclusion that the ConstraintValidatorFactory implementation is not managed by the container and so not can get the BeanManager over JNDI. I will post my Solution in an update of my post.

Comment: @Gas, what is the BeanManager class ? is it javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager ?